# Find the number of files with sizes

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, files

Find the number of files with sizes > 100KB in /, /bin, /usr, /usr/bin and
/usr/sbin directories and output them in a two column format with the name
of the directory and the number of files.

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere ?

Comment: I mean i have to produce the number of files in filesytem(excluding directories) , /bin , /usr like that which is having the file size > 100KB

Comment: In his textbook there is, I guess. I'd suggest `find` and the `-size` option

Comment: Is there anything you tried so far?

Comment: find /home/Desktop -size +100k -type f -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c                (but any other way to do with looping other than this)..

Answer (score 2):

use the `find` command with the `-size` option, a `+` means greater than:

```
find dir1 dir2 -mindepth 1 -type f -size +100k -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

`-mindepth` for excluding the dir itself, `-printf` for printing directory name only, `uniq -c` for counting the times a dir appears, `type` for files only, `sort` as `find`'s output is not necessarily sorted.

Comment: Might want to sort before uniq -c as finds results are not guaranteed to be ordered.

Comment: agreed - side question: would the `-depth` option lead to the same?

Comment: Lead to the same as what?

Comment: to the thing being sorted, as the subdirs would appear first

Comment: No it wouldn't sort it, as it reads the directory in alphabetical(normally) order, so it will go into subdirs then come back to the parent and continue reading files in that.So the count for parent dir can be split into multiple parts if this happens a few times. If it is a single directory then they should be sorted, but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: find /home/Desktop -size +100k -type f -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c
(any other way rather than this one with looping)

Comment: This solution has "bugs": It recurses down the folder tree (which surely the OP won't want), and it prints the output columns in wrong order. And it does not return line in case of "0" big files. Furthermore, if not root, the above prints lots of errors when attempting to traverse e.g. /proc.

Answer (score 1):

For a 2 column output format with "dirName numFiles", where

- "dirName" is one of "/ /bin /usr /usr/sbin"
- "numFiles is the count of files in above directory being >100K

You could also use :

```
$ for i in / /bin /usr /usr/bin; do
    echo -en "$i " ; find $i -maxdepth 1 -size +100k | wc -l;
  done | column -t
```

Example output:

```
/         0
/bin      46
/usr      0
/usr/bin  603
```